# Easy way to dump a table's contents to a ASCII formatted table string?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am debuging some database code  on the Java Platform and it would be convenient to dump the contents of a database table at various points to a log file.

Is there a java library which will take a JDBC connection and a table name and dump all of the contents to a string (ideally formatted into columns properly)?

output should look something like:

```
| col1 | col2 |
| 22   | 55   | 
| 23   | 99   |
```

I know I could write this my self but it feels like the kind of thing that may already be out there. However after lots of searching I have not seen anything.

Would also be interested in any java library for just formatting the ASCI table as I may have to solve the problem my self.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/31887249/32453

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Java. Check if your db has something like the following command (which works for mysql):

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/my_table.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM my_table;
```

EDIT:
If you open the file with a spreadsheet reader like excel, the data will be lined up. Otherwise, not. In order to line up exactly the columns of an ASCII file, the only way that I know is to check the length of each field and add spaces when necessary.

I don't know Java libraries doing this stuff. But it should not particularly difficult to implement. Only a bit tedious...

Comment: will this give me nice lined up columns? That might work for me in some cases but I have 2 databases on the go hear (Orical and Derby) so would probably have to do the db specific solution twice... Im still holding out for a JDBC/java only solution.

Answer (score 0):

[DbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) has methods to import and [export](http://www.dbunit.org/faq.html#extract) database tables to and from [XML](http://www.dbunit.org/apidocs/org/dbunit/dataset/xml/FlatXmlDataSet.html) form. You will have to add the code to write it into a file yourself.

Comment: Thanks but I dont wont xml.  I wont a asci table of data for humans to read.

Comment: You *won't* or you *don't want to*?

Comment: The text is to be used by humans not computers so the format shown in my (updated) question would be most convent.  The code to dump it to a log file is no problem.