# How do you get values from all columns using ResultSet.getBinaryStream() in jdbc?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2, resultset

How do I to write an entire table to a flat file (text file) using jdbc? So far I've attempted the following:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
   ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tablename");
   BufferedInputStream buffer;
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("flatfile.txt");
   while(result.next() )
   {
      buffer =  new BufferedInputStream(result.getBinaryStream("????") );
      byte[] buf = new byte[4 * 1024]; //4K buffer
      int len;
      while( (len = buffer.read(buf, 0, buf.length) ) != -1 )
      {
          out.write(buf, 0, len );
      }
   }
   out.close();
```

"????" is just my placeholder. I am stuck on what to pass in as an argument.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do i just replace '????' with "" to obtain all columns or is there another function within ResultSet or some other class to obtain a whole row? I just want the entire row. Not just one column of that record. I don't have db connectivity to test yet so I'm just trying to figure it out in advance so I'm ready.

Comment: `ResultSet` doesn't provide methods that deal with the entire row. You need to deal with columns individually. You might find the [getMetaData()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData--) method useful.

Comment: Plus `getBinaryStream()` only works for `BLOB` columns - nothing else.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought and java.sql.Statement doesn't seem to have anything other than executeQuery() so is there some other class that would help with this?

Comment: don't know exactly what you want to do... you could just try the DBMS native dump command (all decent DBMSes have one), which is probably easier and faster to use.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can get all the column names and the entire data from your table using the code below.
writeToFile method will contain the logic to writing to file (if that was not obvious enough :) )

```
    ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = metadata.getColumnCount();    
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        writeToFile(metadata.getColumnName(i) + ", ");      
    }
    System.out.println();
    while (rs.next()) {
        String row = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            row += rs.getString(i) + ", ";          
        }
        System.out.println();
        writeToFile(row);

    }
```

Comment: ah, too bad there is no ResultSet.getRow method!

Comment: @gokul_uf, To get particular row we have to move cursor to respective row in ResultSet by using absolute(rowNum) then deal with columns within the row. ResultSet.getRow will itself gets confused which row to be returned ??

Answer (score 11):

Here's how I dump a table from a JDBC connection, very useful for debugging if you want to see all rows that are in an in memory (ex: HSQL) DB for instance:

```
  public static void spitOutAllTableRows(String tableName, Connection conn) {
    try {
      System.out.println("current " + tableName + " is:");
      try (PreparedStatement selectStmt = conn.prepareStatement(
              "SELECT * from " + tableName, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
           ResultSet rs = selectStmt.executeQuery()) {
        if (!rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
          System.out.println("no rows found");
        }
        else {
          System.out.println("types:");
          for (int i = 0; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            System.out.print(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1) + ":" + rs.getMetaData().getColumnTypeName(i + 1) + " ");
          }
          System.out.println();
          while (rs.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount() + 1; i++) {
              System.out.print(" " + rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i) + "=" + rs.getObject(i));
            }
            System.out.println("");
          }
        }
      }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

output is like

```
 current <yourtablename> is:
 types:ID:INT YOURCOLUMN1:VARCHAR YOURCOLUMN2:VARCHAR
 ID=1 YOURCOLUMN1=abc YOURCOLUMN2=null
 ID=2 YOURCOLUMN1=def YOURCOLUMN2=ghi
 ...
```

Answer (score 6):

`result.getBinaryStream("????")` will only return for the value for that column as you put as placeholder.

If you want to get all the column, you need to use `ResultSetMetaData` from `ResultSet`

```
    ResultSetMetaData metadata = resultSet.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = metadata.getColumnCount();
    for (int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++) 
    {
        String columnName = metadata.getColumnName(i);
        System.out.println(columnName);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you sendon1982, I guess I can use this to loop through each column in the table using getBinaryCount() and just pass in the column index to print out the whole table. I was juts wondering if there was a way to spit out a whole table with a single function that's all, but this will do.

Comment: You are welcome.
No, you have to use loop to show them one by one.