# Cloud Spanner JSON function size limit

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

Is it possible to return the query results from Spanner to a JSON document?   For example, if the query is to "read all transactions for this account", and return those row / record results into a single JSON strong or document, is this possible ?   If so, what is the size limitation?  ie  how many transaction rows can this hold ?  example - of there wee 400 transactions in a table, could those all go into a JSON doc or string?

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/json_functions

Comment: The URL you provide only talks about how to retrieve data stored in JSON formatted string in the query, not the other way around (turning the result into a JSON string. Also, is it possible that you read all the rows first and then convert the whole result into a JSON using json encoder library?

Comment: yes, possible..   do you have any thoughts on which library is best / fastest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hailong comments, the link you shared retrieved data stored in Json formatted string. Cloud Spanner does not provide a native way to perform this task. If you want to do it, you need to implement it in your code. For example, you can take a look at this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50814792/java-query-resultset-to-json) as a reference. But it will be depend of the language you want to use.

On the other hand, using a gcloud command you can perform it using `gcloud spanner databases execute-sql` and using the --format flag to select the json format as `--format=json` You can take a look at [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/spanner/databases/execute-sql) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--format) for more information about it.

Comment: if the goal is to replicate data between Cloud Spanner and Google Firestore, is there a simpler or better approach ?

Comment: Hi Gordon, since this a bit different, I would recommend you to open a new question about this concern. Nevertheless, as a quick response. The answer is as the above, Spanner does not provide any native way to perform a task like this, so, it would be necessary you implement an app that perform it. Cloud Spanner allows you to export a data base to [Avro](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/export) and  the export is to json files but I am not sure that this helps you